# Could not find module `ember-resolver` imported from `AppName/resolver Ember tests

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-qunit

I am trying to run Ember tests and it gives this error saying Could not find module `ember-resolver` imported from `AppName/resolver.

I am not sure what is causing it.
I am using Ember-cli-2.12.1. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did you try deleting `node_modules` and trying a clean `npm install`?

Comment: @alptugd  I tried that as well but did not work.

Comment: I was almost sure about your answer; but I still wanted to ask it. By the way is that a brand new project? did that happen during an update? can you give more insight?

Comment: @alptugd NO It is not a brand new App . We had updated to 2.12 and I might have missed something after doing this ->

 npm cache clear && bower cache clean && rm -rf node_modules bower_components && npm install && bower install

I am able to solve Ember-resolver issue But now am getting other error saying Error: Could not find module `ember-qunit` imported from test-helper`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am answering this since i have resolved it and if someone come across  this issue then they can solve it.

Steps i did to resolve it.

1. `npm cache clear && bower cache clean && rm -rf node_modules bower_components && npm install && bower install`

cleaned and reinstall Bower component and npm component.

2. `ember init`

Then I started getting error saying could not found module ember-qunit, after digging i found out that i had a lib called cropperjs from bower which was creating some conflict with ember-qunit whenever i import it in ember-cli-build.js , I moved cropperjs to npm node_modules and my tests started running.

Answer (score 4):

This error is also caused by having this in your ember-cli-build.js. 
I was on version 3.4.0 and I had the code below which caused an error.

`app.import({
    development:'bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js'
  });`