# emberjs ember-resolver error on production

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

We just migrated our project from ember-resolver 2.0.3 to ember-resolver 5.0.1. We also updated ember-cli from 2.9.1 to 3.3.0. All of our environments work as they should except production.

We are getting an error of Could not find module 'ember-resolver' imported from ...

I saw that this was an issue back when users upgraded from 2.12 --> 2.17.

Anyone else getting something similar?

ember-cli: 3.3.0
http_parser: 2.7.0
node: 6.10.0
v8: 5.1.281.93
uv: 1.9.1
zlib: 1.2.8
ares: 1.10.1-DEV
icu: 58.2
modules: 48
openssl: 1.0.2k
os: win32 x64
3.10.10

Comment: Have you been able to recreate this issue in a reproduction repo?

Comment: no, i cannot seem to reproduce in a new simple app, just within our migrated project

Comment: are you on the ember discord? https://discordapp.com/invite/zT3asNS

oh! I had an idea, though -- where is 'ember-source' defined? package.json or bower? (it should be in package.json)

Comment: Going to ask the obvious here but how did you update from 2.9.1 to 3.3.0? Did you delete your `node_modules`, `tmp` and `dist`?

Comment: Hi All, it was in the package.json. we don't use bower anymore. and yes we deleted the node_modules, tmp and dist folder.

Comment: the problem was that we had an ember folder in our vendor directiory and for what ever reason it was included into the bundles. after removing that folder the build succeed in production too

Comment: @PopLevente were you using Heroku as well?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in production only. As described in the comments and in this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44772607/1515819, this error seems to be related to cached files that shouldn't be there.

Clearing the build cache worked for me on Heroku:

```
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
```

https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache

Comment: No we didnt use heroku

Comment: @PopLevente It should still be a pointer for you to clean the cache no matter which system you are using